# Based on dropdown value show div inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

The below thing is taking too much time than expected. Been through top stack solutions and somehow got the below thing--

WHAT IS THE SCENERIO

I have an ng-repeat div with dropdown.
[image]

The drop down contains values and based on selection of those values a div will be shown. What I managed is div is shown. But when I choose another item the previous item div gets hidden.

Below are the screen shot and my code
[image]

[image]

As it can be seen that when I select the first item it shows the textbox div. But when I select the next item the first gets hidden. There are essentially two values -- ALL, Fixed. When All selected nothing will be shown and when Fixed is selected the div for that particular item will be shown.

HTML code

```
                    <div class="tst text-success" ng-repeat="(parentIndex, catList) in categoryArray">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        {{catList.categoryName}}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                      <select class="form-control m-b" ng-model="catObj.cats" ng-change="changeOption(catObj,parentIndex)">
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="fixed">Fixed No. Of Records</option>
                        <option value="perfixed">% od Fixed</option>
                      </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3 noPad" ng-if="isShowing==parentIndex">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-small" placeholder="Set Number" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
  $scope.changeOption = function(obVal,index) {
    console.log(obVal);
    console.log(index);
    if(obVal.cats == "All") {
      //$scope.tbx = 0;
    }
    else {
      $scope.isShowing = index;
    }

  }
```

Help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You are changing all repeated objects isShowing data and saying just show x index. Just change the related divs scope.isShowing value and check the isShowing option with true false value related to scope.

Comment: You're using a single boolean $scope variable, `isShowing`, to control the visibility of several divs. That can't possibly work. You should. 1. have an array of objects, each having a `selectedOption` field. 2. use ng-model in your select box to set the `selectedOption` of the object you're editing. 3. use the value of the object's selectedOption to know if the additional input should be visible *for that object*.

Comment: Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EmsXOkGD6i73NIUKhpB3?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet Thanx man. It worked. I probably missed out on the logic of each having an selectedOption logic. Could you please provide your solution as an answer? In that way I could mark as corrected, which might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a **single** boolean $scope variable, `isShowing`, to control the visibility of **several** divs. That can't possibly work.

You should

1. have an array of objects, each having a `selectedOption` field.
2. use ng-model in your select box to set the selectedOption of the object you're editing.
3. use the value of the object's selectedOption to know if the additional input should be visible for that object.

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objects">
  {{ obj.name }}
  <select name="op" ng-model="obj.selectedOption" ng-options="option.value as option.value for option in options"></select>
  <input ng-if="obj.selectedOption !== 'All'" />
</div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [
    {value: 'All'}, 
    {value: 'Fixed'}
  ];

  $scope.objects = [
    {name: 'Twitter', selectedOption: 'All'}, 
    {name: 'News', selectedOption: 'Fixed'}
  ]
});
```